# Regex and Replace Specific Fields of String

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

I need to do some modifications on dynamically generated strings;

**String Example**

> Products [279] Electric Paint Sprayer [21] Airbrush Equipment [109] Spray Tanning Equipment [23] Mini Air Compressor [33] Sand blasting gun [5] Paint Tank [9] Air Spray Gun [26] Pneumatic tools/Air tools [26] Tire Inflating gun [10] Air Riveter [6] Hand Tools [7] Comb/Hair Brush [4]

I want to remove "**Products [279]**" from the beginning (always the same except the numbers) and replace the rest of the string like this "Electric Paint Sprayer [21] **-**  Airbrush Equipment [109] **-** ..."

Comment: Do you really need Regex for such a simple task? have you tried this?`str=str.Substring(str.IndexOf(']')+2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo](http://www.ideone.com/3xQPh)**

```
String sample = @"Products [279] Electric Paint Sprayer [21] Airbrush Equipment [109] Spray Tanning Equipment [23] Mini Air Compressor [33] Sand blasting gun [5] Paint Tank [9] Air Spray Gun [26] Pneumatic tools/Air tools [26] Tire Inflating gun [10] Air Riveter [6] Hand Tools [7] Comb/Hair Brush [4]";

// Remove "Products [#] "
sample = Regex.Replace(sample, @"^Products \[\d+\]\s*", String.Empty);

// Add hyphens
sample = Regex.Replace(sample, @"(\[\d+\])(?=\s*\w)", @"$1 - ");
// the (?=\s*\w) makes sure we only add a hyphen when there's more information
// ahead (and not a hyphen to the end of the string)
```

Outcome:

> Electric Paint Sprayer [21] -  Airbrush Equipment [109] -  Spray Tanning Equipment [23] -  Mini Air Compressor [33] -  Sand blasting gun [5] -  Paint Tank [9] -  Air Spray Gun [26] -  Pneumatic tools/Air tools [26] -  Tire Inflating gun [10] -  Air Riveter [6] -  Hand Tools [7] -  Comb/Hair Brush [4]

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.Remove or String.Replace to do this. Remember that this does not modify that string but returns a new one.

Oh, and to find the Products [XXX], you could use String.SubString(0, String.IndexOf(']')); To find the string that includes the first instance of ']'.

Answer (score 0):

Proceed as follows:

- replace `^\w+\s+\[\d+\]\s+` with nothing (removes `Products [279]<space>` in your example);
- replace `(?<\])(?=\s+.)` with `<space>-` globally.

Comment: thanks #fge, first one works but the second one gives me error.